# How do I inherit parent project(library aar) gradle dependencies in the child project?

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I have a project which has a library aar module, it's dependent on Flatbuffers gradle dependency.

```
api group: 'com.google.flatbuffers', name: 'flatbuffers-java', version: '1.8.0'
```

I export the aar to another project into libs, and along with the library classes - also want to use flatbuffers.

```
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.aar'])
```

I don't want to import Flatbuffers into my child project again.

Is there any solve for this scenario?

Comment: Using api should work. What error are you getting?